# What's it called when, instead of saying 'you,' you say the name of the person you're talking to?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, dialogue

Let's say you're talking to Sarah and you make her upset so you say to her

- "I would hate to make Sarah upset."

Is there a term for using 'Sarah' instead of the usual 'you' here?

Comment: **You're talking to Sarah**! I don't know why you would do this, but it doesn't have a name other than 'addressing her in the third person'.

Comment: For faux formality and distancing: Mommy will not like this. It's also *patronizing* - As a three-year-old, you can understand me only if I prepare your mind for thinking about your mother as you do, third person.

Comment: It can be patronising, but the third person is also sometimes used to address royalty. So the only thing that's certain is that it's not used in normal situations.

Comment: And there’s Bob Dole…

Comment: The situation with third person is sometimes called ["illeism"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illeism). I'm not aware of any equivalent term for second person.

Comment: It's often used when mocking someone. If Sarah is complaining to you and you think she's going overboard, you might say "I would hate to make Sarah upset" with a sarcastic tone of voice. I'm also not aware of a specific term for it.

Comment: upset Sarah, not make Sarah upset.

Answer (score -2):

The verb would be **"naming"** ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naming)):

- 2a. To mention or identify by name ("refused to name a suspect")
- 2b. To accuse by name

"'I would *hate* to inconvenience the *world-renowned pianist* Sarah Smith,' I said to Sarah, rolling my eyes. She didn't get it, though: she thought my **naming** her was a sincere compliment."

Comment: It's not specific enough to be clear in most contexts. You can "name" someone just as easily when they're not in your presence.